# I would like help on finding resources that teach a person to code a radar graph from a csv file

Tags: csv, graph

```
# Plots a radar chart.

from math import pi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import pandas as pd

# These are the required modules to plot the graph

# Set data
cat = ['Blocks', 'Rebounds', 'NoofShotsMade', 'NoofShotsAttempted', 'Steals']
values = [100, 100, 20, 100, 80]

# This is the are where based on the data in the array the
# graph displays the graph with the stated labels

N = len(cat)

x_as = [n / float(N) * 2 * pi for n in range(N)]

# Because our chart will be circular we need to append a copy of the first 
# value of each list at the end of each list with data
values += values[:1]
x_as += x_as[:1]

# Set color of axes
plt.rc('axes', linewidth=0.5, edgecolor="#888888")

# Create polar plot
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

# Set clockwise rotation. That is:
ax.set_theta_offset(pi / 2)
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

# Set position of y-labels
ax.set_rlabel_position(0)

# Set color and linestyle of grid
ax.xaxis.grid(True, color="#888888", linestyle='solid', linewidth=0.5)
ax.yaxis.grid(True, color="#888888", linestyle='solid', linewidth=0.5)

# Set number of radial axes and remove labels
plt.xticks(x_as[:-1], [])

# Set yticks
plt.yticks([20, 40, 60, 80, 100], ["20", "40", "60", "80", "100"])

# Plot data
ax.plot(x_as, values, linewidth=0, linestyle='solid', zorder=3)

# Fill area
ax.fill(x_as, values, 'b', alpha=0.3)

# Set axes limits
plt.ylim(0, 100)

# Draw ytick labels to make sure they fit properly
for i in range(N):
    angle_rad = i / float(N) * 2 * pi

    if angle_rad == 0:
        ha, distance_ax = "center", 10
    elif 0 < angle_rad < pi:
        ha, distance_ax = "left", 1
    elif angle_rad == pi:
        ha, distance_ax = "center", 1
    else:
        ha, distance_ax = "right", 1

    ax.text(angle_rad, 100 + distance_ax, cat[i], size=10, horizontalalignment=ha, verticalalignment="center")

# Show polar plot
plt.show()
```

In short this code how could I amend this to instead of manually entering the data in the array the graph plots the graph using data from a csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Use python module `csv` to load data from file.

Documentation with examples:
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html